# iOS CarFax API Integration Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, nsurlrequest

CarFax API : https://quickvin.carfax.com/1

CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)

Carfax API Returns response like : **The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.**
Your support ID is: 17261474333009919987

so kindly give me suggesstions or any idea about this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access API only from US or Canada only. or you have to use VPN connection of US or Canada.